# Can I log into Azure Portal using Service Account Certificate?

Tags: azure, azure-service-account

Stuff in Azure are secured with Service Accounts.  In order for me to see stuff I need to download the Service Account certificate and then log in via the Azure CLI using the extracted certificate and the Service Account Application Id.  So now I can see everything the Service Account can see, great.  But it is a pain in the neck and slow.  So my question: Can I use the same certificate and credentials to log into the Azure Portal website so I can browse around using the web browser instead?

Answer (score 0):

Using a Service Principal for interactive logins to the Azure Portal is not possible - which is by design. In order to be able to see the same resources as the Service Principal through the Azure Portal, you would require a user account that holds the [Azure RBAC Reader role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#reader) against those resources that are in scope of the Service Principal role assignments.

As you mentioned *performance* being an issue with using the Service Principal login, you could try [Azure Resource Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/overview) queries. These are supported by Azure CLI, Azure PowerShell as well as all the major Azure SDK's. Obviously, this won't bring you the visual experience like the Azure Portal but might resolve the performance piece maybe.

However, requesting/creating a user account that has the corresponding RBAC roles assigned would be the only way to allow you to see the resources through the Azure Portal.